# When would open() fails with EAGAIN?

Tags: android, file, file-io, stderr

I am seeing failures during file open using open() system call. On querying the last error I am seeing 11, EAGAIN (EWOULDBLOCK). I am not seeing this error everytime but intermittently.

I could not understand why I am getting the error. I am sure that the file is only modified by me at this point. Therefore I wanted to know what are the scenarios where we can see EAGAIN failures.

Is there a way to log Android kernel logs to get more detailed information about this failures?

**************** Update ********************

I added retry mechanism and after that my retries are also failing but with File_NOT_FOUND error and this makes sense to me now. I think Some backgroud activity must be holding it and then deleting it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what man page says:
EAGAIN The file descriptor fd refers to a file other than a socket
              and has been marked nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read
              would block.

EAGAIN  Resource temporarily unavailable (may be the same value as EWOULDBLOCK).

So, try again.

Comment: But what are kernel level reasons behind getting these errors?

Comment: I see the updated notes - Hope you understood the meaning of the Error - "Resource Temporarily Available" -  hence "Retry" !